# Conditional formatting columns in a table MS word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have generated VBA code to help set conditional formatting for a table in MS word. I am trying to apply this code to only limited columns in the table. Only columns 5 and 6. Please help.

I have a macro that changes the background colour of a table in Word depending upon the text within the same cell - akin to Excel's conditional formatting rules.

However I want to restrict this to a specific columns - column 5 & 6  in the table.

My code is below; but this is applying it to both columns.

Anyone know how to re-code so it only applies to table column 5 and 6.

```
Sub ColourSelectedTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Cell
    With Selection
      If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        For Each c In .Tables(1).Range.Cells
          Select Case Split(c.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
            Case 1: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case 2: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case 3: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Case 4: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case Else: c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
          End Select
        Next
      End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: .cells(c).columnindex

Comment: What is the `Select Case` acting on? It's not clear what `c.Range.Text` contains. And since that's determining what applies the various colours it would be important to know that? Right now, this code is cycling *all* cells in the table, regardless of column, and applying formatting based on the cell content, as far as I can tell, rather than the column...

Comment: Hi Cindy, I'm not sure what you mean as i am novice VBA user. Have you any ides how to focus on the columns 5 and 6 in the table?